# How to POST from one Page Handler to another?

Tags: asp.net, post, razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am working on a ASP.NET Core 2.0 project using Razor Pages (not MVC).

I have the following flow:

1. User fills out form and POSTs
2. This page's POST handler validates the info and returns Page() if there are issues. If not, handler saves data to database.
3. From here, I want the handler to POST to a different page's POST handler with the validated and saved data from Step 2.

**How do I POST to another page from within a page handler?** Is this the appropriate way to do this kind of thing? The reason I don't want to RedirectToPage() is because I don't want the final page in the sequence to be navigable via GET. The final page should not be accessible via a direct link but should only return on a POST.

I thought about validating/saving the data and setting a boolean "IsValid" and returning the page, checking for that IsValid, and immediately POSTing to the final page via JS. However this feels dirty.

Answer (score 10):

Set the "asp-page" property of the form to your other page.  Then set values in the standard way.

```
<form method="post" asp-page="/pathto/otherpage">
Select Example:<select name="DataForOtherPage">
```

Then in your controller, bind the value...

```
 [BindProperty]
 public string DataForOtherPage { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -4):

### You don't need to cross post!

If possible, you should avoid the cross-post. Do it all under the original action. The action can [return a different view by specifying the view name in the `View` call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View%28System.String%29).

If the target of the cross-post contains complicated logic that you don't want to duplicate, extract it to a common library, and call it from both actions.

For example, instead of

```
ActionResult Action1()
{
    if (canHandleItMyself)
    {
        return View("View1");
    }
    else
    {
        return //Something that posts to action2
    }
}

ActionResult Action2()
{
    DoSomethingComplicated1();
    DoSomethingComplicated2();
    DoSomethingComplicated3();
    DoSomethingComplicated4();
    return View("View2");
}
```

Do something like this:

```
class CommonLibrary
{
    static public void DoSomethingComplicated()
    {
        DoSomethingComplicated1();
        DoSomethingComplicated2();
        DoSomethingComplicated3();
        DoSomethingComplicated4();
    }
}

ActionResult Action1()
{
    if (canHandleItMyself)
    {
        return View("View1");
    }
    else
    {
        CommonLibrary.DoSomethingComplicated();
        return View("View2");
    }
}

ActionResult Action2()
{
    CommonLibrary.DoSomethingComplicated();
    return View("View2");
}
```

### If you really want to cross-post

If you insist on using a cross-post, you will have to render a page that does the post, e.g.

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
    <IMG Src="/Images/Spinner.gif">  <!-- so the user doesn't just see a blank page -->
    <FORM name="MyForm" Action="Action2" Method="Post">
        <INPUT type="hidden" Name="Argument1" Value="Foo">    
        <INPUT type="hidden" Name="Argument2" Value="Bar">
    </FORM>
    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript>
        document.getElementById("MyForm").submit();  //Automatically submit
    </SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I presume cross-posting is bad for some reason other than it being a workaround?

Also, I am using Razor Pages instead of MVC so I am not if I can adapt what you are recommending to my project. The only way that I see of returning another view (razor page) is by calling RedirectToPage, but this points to a Get method instead of POST.

Comment: Downvote, this answer is for MVC Actions and Views, not Razor Page Handlers (technically, MVVM).

Comment: @S-Vuk, cross-posting isn't necessarily bad, but at the moment Razor Pages doesn't offer an equivalent to the old purely server-side `Server.Transfer` method -- you'd need a reference to the other PageModel.

Comment: If you have one page where the user sets the report settings, and another page that does the actual report. I don't see a better approach than to post the first page to the second.