# razor pages form post handling

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a simple html form

```
<form method="post" asp-page="testbank" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="text" name="d" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and I want to post to another razor page called testbank. In the testbank razor page I have

```
public void OnPost()
{
    var a = Request.Form["d"];
}
```

but the post action is not triggered even when I add a breakpoint. I can't figure out why is that happening. I want to post data to another razor page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to POST from one Page Handler to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070149/how-to-post-from-one-page-handler-to-another)

Comment: the problem is that  i can't trigger the post action even with a breakpoint in my code

Comment: ok the error was typo  i had the method as onPostAsync   but the correct is OnPostAsync